Block Matrices and minimal, characteristic polynomials
For context, I'm a second year undergraduate maths student, preparing for my exams.
Let $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$, and suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, a field.
Suppose $T$ is the linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^n$ with matrix

I've shown that $\chi_T(x) = (-1)^n f(x), m_T(x) = f(x)$.
Say $B$ is the matrix

where there are $N$ blocks in each row and column.
I want to show that for all $i,j$,

if $j<i$, then for all $k$, the $(k,k+i)$th block in $B^j$ is $0$,
if $j \geq i$, then there is a constant $\beta_{i,j}$ such that for all $k$, the $(k,k+i)$th block in $B^j$ is $\beta_{i,j} A^{j-1}$,
if $m_T(x)$ is irreducible, then for all $k$, the $(k,k+1)$th block of $m_T(B)$ is $g(A)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$ which is coprime to $m_T(x)$,

Finally, I want to find the minimal and characteristic polynomials of a linear transformation $U$ with matrix $B$.
I've tried writing $B = A\tilde{I} + \tilde{X}$ where $A$ is like a scalar block matrix (if that even exists) and $I$ is the identity matrix and $X$ is the matrix with $1$s above the diagonal and $0$s elsewhere. Then, I did $B^2$, then $B^3$, but didn't spot a pattern.
I see that the block entries above the diagonal are filled up in diagonal lines, so for example B has the diagonal and a super diagonal and the rest of the entries are $0$, $B^2$ has the diagonal, and two super diagonals above it and the rest of the entries are $0$. In general, $B^j$ has its diagonal and $j-1$ super diagonals above the diagonal and the rest are $0$, so for $j<i$, for all $k$, the $(k,k+i)$th block in $B^j$ is $0$. How I make this rigorous, I need help with.
For the second part, I see the super diagonals are filled, but I must be computing incorrectly- it's not of the form $\beta_{i,j} A^{j-1}$, and includes other powers of $A$. How to go from here?
Any hints would be greatly appreciated, especially on how to handle these block matrices type of questions!
